# Calculate the nature of the following series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Can someone help me determinate the nature of the following series?
$$ \frac {a^n}{ (1 + tg(\frac{3}{2}) ( 1+tg(\frac {3}{4}) + ... (1 + tg(\frac{3}{2n})) }$$

Comment: Are you looking for the limit of this, or for the limit of the sum of this?

Comment: A sequence or series.?

Comment: Series! 
I tried Raabe-Duhamel but to no avail.

Comment: Raabe's test is enough. $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}n\tan\left(\frac{3}{2n}\right)=\frac{3}{2}>1$$ ensures that the given series is convergent at $a=1$. The denominator behaves like $n^{3/2}$.